# Update end date based on next start date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to update end date based on first start date. i am able to do using select query but i need to update it in pure mysql

Here is my fiddle with select

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c7W93g4ypSmGqPKfuvBtgL/0

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.FOCUS, t1.DATE AS STARTDATE, t2.DATE AS ENDDATE
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t2.DATE = (SELECT MIN(DATE)
                                  FROM table1 t3
                                  WHERE t3.DATE > t1.DATE)
```

Comment: You need to update on a table? On a same table?

Comment: yes, same table

Comment: You need to add new column first (and maybe change `DATE` column name to `STARTDATE`).. then switch your working `SELECT` query to `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Or create another table with the additional column then do `INSERT` from your query above.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT t1.ID, t1.FOCUS, t1.DATE StartDate, MIN(t2.DATE) EndDate
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.DATE < t2.DATE
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.FOCUS, t1.DATE
```

and respectively

```sql
UPDATE table1
JOIN (SELECT t1.ID, MIN(t2.DATE) EndDate
      FROM table1 t1
      LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.DATE < t2.DATE
      GROUP BY t1.ID) data_for_update
SET table1.ENDDATE = data_for_update.EndDate
WHERE table1.ID = data_for_update.ID;
```